# How to override errors templates for Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.2

I want to override the error templates in Symfony 3. I've started by creating a TwigBundle folder withe the personalised twig.

```
app/
 └─ Resources/
    └─ TwigBundle/
      └─ Exception/
        ├─ error404.html.twig
        ├─ error403.html.twig
        ├─ error.html.twig
```

Then I checked the `routing_dev` file which contains this lines :

```
_errors:
resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
prefix:   /_error
```

Symfony still displays the default error templates. I want to know if I should verify something else.

PS : I have already checked this documentation : [How to Customize Error Pages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#replace-the-default-exception-controller)

**EDIT** :

[image]

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: Could just be a typo in your question but your "Resources" folder has 2 s's... "Ressources/"

Comment: @naththedeveloper It is a typo error in the question, but the folder already exists and named "Resources"

Comment: Be aware that those overriden error templates do **not** show up in the `dev` environment. 

If you want to test the templates you need to access `/_error/<error-code>.html` (i.e. `localhost:8000/_error/404.html` with the integrated webserver)

Comment: right. But the correct link is localhost:8000/_error/404.html _error and not _errors

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The overriden files should reside in a subfolder named `views`. The correct file tree would look like this:

```
app/
 └─ Resources/
    └─ TwigBundle/
        └─ views/
            └─ Exception/
                ├─ error404.html.twig
                ├─ error403.html.twig
                ├─ error.html.twig
```

Clear your cache afterwards.

Be aware that those overriden error templates do **NOT** show up in the `dev` environment.

If you want to test the templates in your `dev` environment you must ensure you have imported the following in `routing_dev.yml`:

```
_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error
```

Now you can access `/_error/<error-code>.html` (i.e. `localhost:8000/_error/404.html` with the integrated webserver)

Comment: Surely the views reside inside the TwigBundle directory?

Comment: You're correct. It has to be the other way around. Still the missing `views` folder sems to be the issue here. Edited my answer.